# Why my array class is unable find out the minimum and maximum value of a randomly generated array?

Tags: java, arrays, random, max, minimum

I have created an array with random numbers which will also show maximum and minimum element of the array,the program is successfully compiled.But on run the maximum value:0
minimum value:0
while the generated array is correct.Please help me out to rectify the wrong logic.

```
class ArrayTest
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        int a[];
        a=new int[10];
        System.out.println("Storing the random values in Array Elements");
        System.out.println("Maximum:"+getMax(a));
        System.out.println("Minimum:"+getMin(a));
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            a[i]=(int)(Math.random()*100);
        }
        System.out.println("\n List of Elements:");
        int sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(a[i]);
        }
    }


    //Maximum Value Finding
    public static int getMax(int[] a)
    {
        int max=a[0];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]>max)
            {
                max=a[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    //Minimum Values Finding
    public static int getMin(int[] a)
    {
        int min=a[0];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]<min)
            {
                min=a[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You call the getMax and getMin BEFORE you fill the array.